# how to establish relation between any two nodes of d3 tree layout

Tags: d3.js

I have a D3 tree layout.There will be relation between any two nodes,based on this relation i want to show some connection between 2 nodes.Till now i was using circles.on onmouse circles of the 2 nodes will be in some specified color.circles were not covering images exaclty.so i applied transform but it disturbing some other functionalities.

my sole purpose is to show some connection between any two nodes using circles or something else.i tried applying  circles using CSS3 but it didnt work

is there any  way to achieve my requirement[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you, there are different ways to achieve this, and this is only one.

Consider this:

```
function highlight() {
    var selectedClass = d3.select(this).attr("class");
    d3.selectAll("circle")
        .style("fill",function(d) {  
            if ( selectedClass == d3.select(this).attr("class"))
                return "magenta";
        });
}
```

Assuming you have established the relationship between any given number of nodes (two or more) by assigning them the same class (perhaps a big assumption), then code like the one above can display such relationship. If you click on one of the nodes (this function is called by the node `.on("click"...`), the others will also display the desired change, illustrated here by a change in color. Does this help?